# Sharp GP2Y0A710K0F IR sensor behaving strangely

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, analogread, ir

I have just purchased a new Sharp GP2Y0A710K0F IR sensor online. As a sanity check, I wrote this simple code to check if the sensor is working correctly. The code is expected to print output voltage from the sensor, which is based on the distance

```
int sensorpin = A5;     
int val = 0;    

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{
val = analogRead(sensorpin);
Serial.println(val);   
delay(100); 
}
```

Now the output is quite strange. The output values start from zero and keep on increasing until they reach 1023, and then gradually decrease down to zero and this keeps on happening, even if something is kept in front of the sensor.

Is my sensor a faulty one? or is it supposed to give out similar outputs. If it has to, how do I convert these values to meter or centimeters.

The product description on the manufacturer's website said that it has a 3 pin interface, however it has a 5 pin one, the wires being Red, Black, Yellow, White, Green if seen from the left side. I guessed from the [datasheet](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AnWPsNx8qqvugs0YNoXsvMuq2orDBQ) that Red and Black are for power and Yellow for signal output and hence I have connected only these 3 wires. The Green and White wires are unconnected. Also, pin numbers aren't marked.

Comment: The datasheet says there are 5 pins. 2 are Vcc and 2 are ground.

Comment: How close is "in front of the sensor"?

Comment: @Majenko , so I connected the Red and Black wires as Vcc and ground respectively. Used the yellow wire for output.

Comment: @Majenko roughly 40-50 cm away, it is supposed to be atleast 100 cm away right?

Comment: Well, that's probably why then. Does the graph on page 5 of the datasheet look like what you are describing? Also, did you note the description? `Distance Measuring Sensor Unit
Measuring distance: 100 to 550 cm
Analog output type`

Comment: @Majenko I tested with an object placed at about 200 m. Still the same problem. Since the object is at a constant distance, the reading should be stable right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have it wired wrongly.

You need to consult the outline diagram in the datasheet and work out which colour wire is which function. It's this bit:

[image]

By your wiring description it sounds like you may be powering it through Vo and reading the result through VCC, which won't work - and at worst may damage it.

Comment: Did the experiment, connected pin 3 to 5v on Arduino, 5 to GND on Arduino and 4 to A5. This time the readings start off with 927 and go to 1023 and then come back to 927 and the process repeats.

Comment: I think I have got it working. Connected both the postives to 5v and both the ground to 5v, I then get the voltage readings ranging between 355-388. If that's 3.5 to 3.8v, its horribly wrong as then according to the graph,it should be roughly 2v as the object is 1.5 m away from the sensor

Comment: Those are raw ADC values. You have to convert them to voltage.

Comment: But anyways, since I've got the sensor working, how to read its values is another question. Thanks